# restrict a user's directories

Tags: linux, permissions, account-restrictions

I have some running project with logging directories. I wish to create a user that has only read access to those directories so that he will be used by a third party to investigate deployment problems.

The directory tree is like this:

```
- project dir a
-logging dirs
    - dir 1 
    - dir2
```

I have 3 other users in a group called `h1` that have access to all of the directories and the wished user will be granted with read rights on `dir2` only.

Can you please help me with that

Answer (score 0):

You should understand and apply the Access Control List (ACL) :

[how-to-use-getfacl-and-setfacl-to-get-and-set-access-control-lists-acls-on-directories-in-linux](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2955/how-to-use-getfacl-and-setfacl-to-get-and-set-access-control-lists-acls-on-directories-in-linux)

In hoping that's helping.